# Can we open .gz format dataset without extracting in R or Python?

Tags: python, r, dataset

dataset information link in below, thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In R:

```r
gzfile("/path/to/file/steam.sql.gz")
```

Answer (score 0):

For python you can use **gzip** library.

`import gzip`
`data1 = gzip.open('stream.sql.gz', 'r')`
`data = data1.readlines()`
`data1.close()`
`print(data)`